# Unable to collect all the lines under transactions from a pdf file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, pdfplumber

I'm trying to extract all the lines under the transactions table from this [pdf file](https://disclosures-clerk.house.gov/public_disc/ptr-pdfs/2016/20005444.pdf). The script that I've created can scrape the first line under the first and last headers. How can I collect all the lines from that page?

```
import os
import io
import re
import requests
import pdfplumber

pdf_url = 'https://disclosures-clerk.house.gov/public_disc/ptr-pdfs/2016/20005444.pdf'

response = requests.get(pdf_url)

with io.BytesIO(response.content) as f:
    with pdfplumber.open(f) as pdf:
        text_content = ""
        for page in pdf.pages:
            text_content += page.extract_text()

pattern = r'(?:iD owner asset transaction Date notification amount cap\.\s*type Date gains >\s*\$200\?\s*|iD owner asset transaction Date notification(?: amount)?\s*type Date\s*)\s*([^\n]+)'
matches = re.findall(pattern, text_content, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
for match in matches:
    print(match.strip())
```

Current output:

```
JT Agnico Eagle Mines limited (AEM) S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $15,001 - $50,000
FIlINg STATuS: New
u.S. global Jets ETF (JETS) P 07/1/2016 07/1/2016 $1,001 - $15,000
```

For your reference, this is the type of line I'm interested in:

`Agnico Eagle Mines limited (AEM) S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $15,001 - $50,000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use simpler strategy - find all lines with `$`:

```py
import pdfplumber
import requests

pdf_url = "https://disclosures-clerk.house.gov/public_disc/ptr-pdfs/2016/20005444.pdf"

response = requests.get(pdf_url)

with io.BytesIO(response.content) as f:
    with pdfplumber.open(f) as pdf:
        out = []
        for page in pdf.pages:
            for line in page.extract_text().splitlines():
                if "$" in line:
                    out.append(line.removeprefix("JT "))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    "Agnico Eagle Mines limited (AEM) S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $15,001 - $50,000",
    "Agnico Eagle Mines limited (AEM) S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "barrick gold Corporation (AbX) S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "Eldorado gold Corporation Ordinary S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "First Trust ISE-Revere Natural gas S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "goldcorp Inc. (gg) S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $15,001 - $50,000",
    "goldcorp Inc. (gg) S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "Kinross gold Corporation (KgC) S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "Newmont Mining Corporation (NEM) S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "Newmont Mining Corporation (NEM) S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "North American Palladium, ltd. (PAl) S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "Pan American Silver Corp. (PAAS) S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "Pilot gold, Inc Ordinary Shares (PlgTF) S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "Pinetree Capital ltd Ordinary Shares S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "Rare Element Resources ltd. Ordinary S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "Silver Wheaton Corp Common Shares S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "Silver Wheaton Corp Common Shares S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "SPdR S&P International dividend ETF P 07/1/2016 07/1/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "u.S. global Jets ETF (JETS) P 07/1/2016 07/1/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
    "Yamana gold Inc. Ordinary Shares S 06/29/2016 06/30/2016 $1,001 - $15,000",
]
```